# Does the $3s$ orbital contain the $2s$ orbital?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

The following image is in my introductory chemistry textbook:

[image]

It seems to imply that the $3s$ orbital “contains” the $2s$ and 1s orbital. That is, a $3s$ electron could find itself in a region of space that is “normally” occupied by a $1s$ or $2s$ electron — a region closer to the nucleus. However, if it is closer to the nucleus, wouldn’t it be in a lower energy state and therefore not a $n=3$ electron?

Answer (score 1):

The energy state of the electron is defined by the orbital (in more sophisticated language, we would say that it is defined by the energy eigenstate). Two electrons with two different orbitals are in distinct states, even if one orbital is non-zero in a location where the other orbital is also non-zero.

Because of the uncertainty principle, in an atom an electron with a known position does not have a definite energy, and an electron with a known energy does not have a definite position. The orbitals define electron states of definite energy, and therefore we don't know where the electron is. There is merely some probability to find the electron somewhere. The different orbitals define different energy states of the electron. There is no requirement that only one orbital can be non-zero at a given point in space.

Here is a somewhat more sophisticated version of this answer. The states of two different energy levels, call the states $\psi$ and $\chi$ are different if the overlap between them is zero. You are essentially defining "overlap" to mean "if both $\chi(x)\neq 0$ and $\psi(x)\neq0$ for some $x$, then $\chi$ and $\phi$ overlap." This is not a useful definition quantum mechanically. Really, what we mean by overlap is the *inner product* of the two states. Two different energy levels *do* have zero overlap in this sense. In equations:
\begin{equation}
\langle \chi | \psi \rangle = \int d^3 x \chi^\star(x) \psi(x) = 0
\end{equation}